# query with nexted joins taking a very long time

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables:
domains:
    :has many => channels
        :has_many => sales
        :has_many => visits

I'm trying to get all my domains, channels count, sales count and visits count for each domain in this query:

```
SELECT
    kd.id, kd.domain,
    COUNT(distinct kc.id) AS channels_count,
    COUNT(distinct kv.id) AS visits_count,
    COUNT(distinct kv.ip_address) AS visitors_count,
    COUNT(distinct ks.id) AS sales_count
FROM
    domains AS kd
LEFT JOIN
    channels AS kc
    ON(kc.domain_id=kd.id)
LEFT JOIN
    sales AS ks
    ON(ks.channel_id=kc.id)
LEFT JOIN
    visits AS kv
    ON(kv.channel_id=kc.id)
GROUP BY kd.id
```

I have a few thousand records in sales and visits table, nothing big but my query takes forever. It never comes back. Any idea why?

db: postgresql

Comment: for that amount of records, you need implement indexes. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/indexes.html

Comment: Do you have foreign keys defined on the related tables `kc.domain_id, kv.channel_id, kv.channel_id`, and consequently indexes?

Comment: Yes I have indexes on all joining points. An explain shows an excessive amount of records being pulled so I guess it's something wrong with the fact the I have to join my channels table with 2 more tables but I just can't seem to find anything wrong.

Comment: If you've got indexes then it's probably the count(distinct that is doing it. Have you tried to exclude the COUNT(distinct kv.ip_address) and see what response you get? A distinct over a string field is probably not going to be fast if you;ve got a lot of records.

Comment: there's no string field. Ip addresses are 10 digit integers saved as long (long2ip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNT(DISTINCT) can be a resource hog.  In addition, your tables probably have many duplicates on the "kd.id" column, resulting in zillions of rows being generated.

A more efficient approach is to do the aggregation first, and then join the results together.  I think the following query does what you want (I'm assuming that the id columns are unique in each table):

```
SELECT kd.id, kd.domain, channels_count, visits_count,
       visitors_count, sales_count
FROM domains kd LEFT JOIN
     (select kc.domain_id, count(*) as channels_count
      from channels kc
      group by kc.domain_id
     ) kc
     ON(kc.domain_id=kd.id) LEFT JOIN
     (select ks.channel_id, count(*) as sales_count
      from sales ks
      group by ks.channel_id
     ) ks
     ON(ks.channel_id=kc.id) LEFT JOIN
     (select kv.channel_id, count(*) as visits_count,
             count(distinct ipaddress) as visitors_count
      from visits kv
      on kv.channel_id
     )
     ON(kv.channel_id=kc.id)
```

GROUP BY kd.id

Comment: I wish it could be cleaner but it's perfect in terms of results. Thanks.